# Rails 3.1 Model Inheritance without Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Most inheritance questions I've seen assume that the child classes have different attributes than the super class.  For example, `Person` may be the super class, and `Driver` a subclass, where `Driver` has everything `Person` has plus a `license_type` field.

I'm asking a slightly different question.  I have a super class, call it `Entity`, and `Entity` has an `object_type` field, describing what type of `Entity` we have.  All types have the same fields, but each type behaves slightly differently.  For example, the `add` method is different for different `Entity` types.

My currently solution is to subclass `Entity` and whenever I fetch an `Entity` (e.g., in `find()` or `where(..)`), I call `entity = entity.becomes(eval("Entity#{entity.object_type}"))`.  This is ugly and doesn't work that well, for example `url_for` and `form_for` will call undefined methods, because the class type is `Entity<Type>`, not `Entity`.

How would I go about having model inheritance without table inheritance, such that urls, paths, forms, and everything else still works as described?  And maybe there's a way for me to avoid calling `.becomes(..)`, too?  What I'm doing is very ugly ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've learned more about Ruby and Rails and I've come up with a good solution.  I changed my `Entity<Type>` classes to modules and put them in `lib/`.  Then, in the Entity class, I have an `after_initialize` callback that looks like this:

```
if object_type == "Type1"
  extend EntityType1
elsif object_type == "Type2"
  extend EntityType2
end
```

This way, all the methods defined in `EntityType1` and `EntityType2` are executed in the scope of the `Entity` class, without requiring any new class instantiation.  So far the solution has been working well, though I've only been using it for a few days now.